# Stripe first Subscription payment missing meta data

Tags: c#, .net, stripe-payments

I am using stripe API and .net to create subscriptions.

my issue is that when i create a subscription the meta data is saved on the subscription instead of being saved on the payment.
is there a way to save the meta data on the first subscription payment instead?

that is what i have tried so far :

```
        var subscriptionOptions = new SubscriptionCreateOptions
        {
            Customer = customerID,
            Items = new List<SubscriptionItemOptions>
            {
                new SubscriptionItemOptions
                {
                    Price = priceID,
                    Quantity = 1
                },
            },
            PaymentBehavior = "default_incomplete",
            Metadata = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { "id", "123"},
                    { "name", "david" },
                },
        };
        subscriptionOptions.AddExpand("latest_invoice.payment_intent");
        var subscriptionService = new SubscriptionService();
        try
        {
            Subscription subscription = await subscriptionService.CreateAsync(subscriptionOptions);

            return new SubscriptionCreateResponse
            {
                SubscriptionId = subscription.Id,
                ClientSecret = subscription.LatestInvoice.PaymentIntent.ClientSecret,
            };
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the subscription `metadata` is not propagated to the generated invoices or the payment intents used within those invoices. If you want `metadata` on either of those, you'll need to set up a process to update that using your own code.

You could, for example, set this up using webhooks. You could listen for `invoice.paid` webhooks and then retrieve the subscription to get the `metadata` and update the Payment Intent related to that invoice.